# Is it possible to use unicode characters in a Win32 resource file?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, unicode, dialog

I have a Win32 program where the main window is a dialog box, so I can create all the controls using the resource.rc file. I'm stuck at creating a button using a unicode character though. It works with using the CreateWindowEx() function, but not in the resource file. Why is that?

I've tried the following lines of code in my resource file:

```
#include <wchar.h> // tried with and without this header file
// also tried defining UNICODE but i got an error saying it was already defined
CONTROL "\u2190", IDC_BACK //...more stuff
CONTROL L"\u2190", IDC_BACK //...more stuff
```

Comment: Yes is possible use Unicode in resource files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use non-ASCII characters in a resource, you can either save the .rc file in UTF-16 with a BOM, or else save the file in Ansi and use a `#pragma codepage` directive to indicate the file's codepage.  I would suggest UTF-16.  Either way, you can then use the actual character instead of using `"\u"`:

```
CONTROL "←", IDC_BACK
```