# Using unicode in win32 .rc file compiled with GCC

Tags: winapi, gcc, unicode, rc

I have the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897512/is-it-possible-to-use-unicode-characters-in-a-win32-resource-file) - the unicode characters from a resource file aren't displayed correctly (`LTEXT L"żółć", - 1, 5, 5, 80, 10` results in [image: unicode displayed incorrectly]). However solutions in the answer to that question don't work for GCC, because 1) [utf-16 doesn't work with GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65130234/c-file-encoded-in-utf-16-is-not-read-properly-by-gcc) and 2) there's no `#pragma codepage` in GCC.

**EDIT** - minimal reproducible exmaple:
main.cpp

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
    if(msg == WM_COMMAND && LOWORD(wparam) == IDCANCEL) {
        EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE thisInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int) {
    DialogBox(thisInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(123), nullptr, DialogProc);
    return 0;
}
```

dialog.rc

```rc
#include <windows.h>
123 DIALOG 100, 100, 100, 100
STYLE WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION
{
    LTEXT L"żółć", -1, 0, 0, 100, 100
}
```

Comment: Have the GNU folks fix their tooling then, or stop using them (which is, ultimately, the sane option).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. In particular, do not use images of text; show the text itself…

Comment: I added MRE. As for the text - I couldn't copy it and an image to text donverter didn't work out as there were exotic characters in the text.

Comment: For a standard dialog (as used in the code) you can press Ctrl+C and have a textual representation of the dialog placed into the clipboard.